# Configure Traefik in front of two docker containers, all on port 80

Tags: docker, traefik

I try to run three docker containers on one host. Traaefik is one of the containers to proxy traffic to the other containers.

My first goal is to reach each container through a dedicated hostname on port 80. Traefik ui should be available only through a hostname and on port 80 also, having some sort of authentication.

Using only a docker-compose.yml, I can reach all three containers using the hostnames, all on port 80. But to add authentication, I guess I need to introduce a traefik.toml. But this gives me troubles.
Next goal would be to introduce SSL using let's encrypt on all three hosts.But first things first...

Working solution with three hosts, all on port 80, lacking authorization for Traefik UI:

```
version: "2"

networks:
 web:

services:

 prox:
    image: containous/traefik:latest # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Træfik to listen to docker
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
    labels:
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.backend=traefikception"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.test.com"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
    networks:
      - web

 seafile_1:
    image: seafileltd/seafile
    container_name: seafile_1
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      SEAFILE_ADMIN_EMAIL: me@test.com
      SEAFILE_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ####
      SEAFILE_SERVER_HOSTNAME: 1.test.com
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:1.test.com
      - traefik.port=80
      - traefik.backend=seafile_1
      - traefik.docker.network=web
    volumes:
      - /opt/seafile-data/ttt_1:/shared
    networks:
      - web

 seafile_2:
    image: seafileltd/seafile
    container_name: seafile_2
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      SEAFILE_ADMIN_EMAIL: me@test2.com
      SEAFILE_ADMIN_PASSWORD: #####
      SEAFILE_SERVER_HOSTNAME: 2.test2.com
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:2.test2.com
      - traefik.port=80
      - traefik.backend=seafile_1
      - traefik.docker.network=web
    volumes:
      - /opt/seafile-data/ttt_2:/shared
    networks:
      - web
```

Adding the following traefik.toml:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"

 [entryPoints.proxy]
   address=":80"
   [entryPoints.proxy.auth]
     [entryPoints.proxy.auth.basic]
       users = [
         "joh:$apr1$RKdHyOKO$QDK1EKB4UJbsda7CXfPfK0",
       ]

[api]
entrypoint="proxy"
```

I get lot's of the following errors in the log, none of the containers is reachable from outside:

```
prox_1           | time="2018-06-17T19:23:26Z" level=fatal msg="Error preparing server: listen tcp :8080: bind: address already in use"
prox_1           | time="2018-06-17T19:24:26Z" level=error msg="Error opening listener listen tcp :8080: bind: address already in use"
prox_1           | time="2018-06-17T19:24:26Z" level=fatal msg="Error preparing server: listen tcp :8080: bind: address already in use"
```

I am pretty sure I need to adapt my docker-compose.yml and move settings to traefik.toml, but I cannot get my head around how to to that.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you're mapping port 80 on the host to 80 on your proxy container. The proxy container is clearly running on port 8080, and it's not often that you can use 80 on the host either. Even your label suggests that 8080 is being used. I think that mapping should be 8080:8080

Comment: What makes you think that you can reach your service containers on port 80 through the host? You haven't exposed that port for those containers, so if you're doing so it must be through your proxy.

Comment: I guess I am running treafik as a backend. The line traefik.port=8080 tells traefik to connect to this backend on container port 8080. Yes, I hope I am reaching all three containers through the proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of traefik support on slack I was able to solve this.

1. you may not have more than one entryPoint per Port
2. The Authorization can be configured in the docker-compose.yml
3. add acme.json and configure https and Let's encrypt only in traefik.toml

In /opt/traefik put the following three files:

**acme.json:**

may be empty but must be well secured:

```
touch acme.json
chmod 600 acme.json
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "2"

networks:
 web:

services:

 prox:
    image: containous/traefik:latest # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Træfik to listen to docker
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
#     - "8080:8080" # Don't want this port open (on all hostnames!)
    labels:
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.backend=traefikception"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.example.me"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.auth.basic=admin:$$ert2$$RKdHyOKO$$QDK1EKB4UJbsda7CXfPfK0"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - "./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml"
      - "./acme.json:/acme.json"
    networks:
      - web

seafile_org1:
    image: seafileltd/seafile
    container_name: seafile_org1
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      SEAFILE_ADMIN_EMAIL: mail@mail.me
      SEAFILE_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ####
      SEAFILE_SERVER_HOSTNAME: org1.example.me
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:org1.example.me
      - traefik.port=80
      - traefik.backend=seafile_org1
      - traefik.docker.network=web
    volumes:
      - /opt/seafile-data/org1:/shared
    networks:
      - web

 seafile_org2:
    image: seafileltd/seafile
    container_name: seafile_org2
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      SEAFILE_ADMIN_EMAIL: mail@mail.com
      SEAFILE_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ####
      SEAFILE_SERVER_HOSTNAME: org2.example.com
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:org2.example.com
      - traefik.port=80
      - traefik.backend=seafile_org2
      - traefik.docker.network=web
    volumes:
      - /opt/seafile-data/org2:/shared
    networks:
      - web
```

get what you need to put as value to traefik.frontend.auth.basic issuing:

```
htpasswd -n admin
```

**traefik.toml:**
    defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"

  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
[entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[api]
dashboard = true


# Enable ACME (Let's Encrypt): automatic SSL.
[acme]
email = "you@mail.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
# If true, display debug log messages from the acme client library.
# acmeLogging = true
# Enable certificate generation on frontends host rules.
onHostRule = true
# CA server to use.
# Uncomment the line to use Let's Encrypt's staging server,
# leave commented to go to prod.
caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
# Use a HTTP-01 ACME challenge.
# Optional (but recommended)
[acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"
```

This uses Let's encrypt staging environment to get you three certs. Comment the line with caServer to get the real certs! Recreate an empty acme.json as well!

The seafile-data is stored in

```
/opt/seafile-data/org1
```

and

```
/opt/seafile-data/org2
```

respectively.

In /opt/traefik you can start the system:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

and watch the logs with

```
docker-compose logs
```

Startup takes some time on first run to setup seafile, get the certs,...

Your hosts should be reachable, giving no SSL errors or warnings on

- http://traefik.example.me (Asking your credentials to see the page)
- http://org1.example.me
- http://org2.example.com

What's left to do is to edit the ccnet.conf file in each of the seafile installation directories (/opt/seafile-data/org1/seafile/conf/ccnet.conf) and change the protocol to "http" and remove the port ":8000" from SERVICE_URL so that shared links are correct for that setup as well. The line should read:

```
SERVICE_URL = https://org1.example.me
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in the Docker Stacks file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.7.13
    command: >
      --api
      --docker
      --docker.swarmmode
      --docker.watch
      --docker.exposedbydefault=false
      # --debug=true
      --loglevel=error # debug
      --defaultentrypoints=https,http
      --entryPoints="Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https"
      --entryPoints="Name:https Address::443 TLS"
      --retry
      --acme=true
      --acme.entrypoint=https
      --acme.httpchallenge
      --acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=http
      --acme.domains="..."
      --acme.email="..."
      --acme.storage=/certs/acme.json
    ports:
      - 80:80     # HTTP
      - 443:443   # HTTPS
      - 8080:8080 # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - acme:/certs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    deploy:
      labels:
        traefik.frontend.rule: Path:/whoami
        traefik.enable: "true"
        traefik.port: 80

volumes:
  acme:
```